# Excel Multiple XLA AddIns use at the same time

Tags: excel, vba, excel-addins

can two excel add ins (named differently but containing the same code) be used at once? And how do I easily select which one to use when running macro over ribbon link for example?

I have add in with a lot of code being used in many Excel files, but want to split production and developer add in (only make changes in developer add in).

But since add in settings is global for all Excel files, how do I select that I want to use dev or prod add in?

I can't get rid of production altogether, because I regularly need to work with both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean you want an easier method to switch between 2 addins (dev and production) then don't use the Excel addin manager, just open the addin you want as if it was a workbook.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of that anymore since I started using add in manager.